# How can I link to a Google Map that shows directions from “My Location” to a Place ID?

Tags: api, geolocation, google-maps

This URL takes me to a place ID:

https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=Google&query_place_id=ChIJaXQRs6lZwokRY6EFpJnhNNE

This URL gives me directions from my current location to the specified address:

https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=20+W+34th+St+New+York+NY+13204

How can I combine those two URLs together to go from my current location to a place ID? I tried [this](https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=place_id:ChIJaXQRs6lZwokRY6EFpJnhNNE), but it doesn't seem to work, and I can't find any documentation for it.

Comment: Questions on **the use of third party web applications** are off-topic for Pro Webmasters. You may be able to get help on [webapps.se]. I recommend reading their [FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com//about) to ensure your question is appropriate for their site.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action).

You have to use `origin`, `destination`, and `destination_place_id` as the parameters. The `destination` parameter is required even if you're using a `destination_place_id`, but the `destination_place_id` takes priority.

Here's a working example: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=My+Location&destination=20+W+34th+St,+New+York,+NY+10001&destination_place_id=ChIJaXQRs6lZwokRY6EFpJnhNNE